# How to call default multimethod from within multimethod

Tags: clojure

Suppose I have a multimethod:

```
(defmethod print-method MyObject [obj writer] 
    (.write writer (format "%s %s" 
                           "prefix" 
                           (original-print-method-placeholder obj writer))
```

I want to emit some arbirtary string, then the orginal string that would have been generated had I not defined `print-method` for this object.

So how do I call the "original" `print-method` with this object as argument?

Comment: Is that a Java object with the original print-method?

Comment: In my specific case it's actually a `defrecord`.  I want to modify how the `defrecord` prints out for both cases of `*print-dup*` being true or false.  In the normal case `pprint` just emits the map value inside the brackets without the class name.  I want to use this output since it does the line breaks properly, but prepend it with my own custom version of the class name, ie without the `#my.namespace.TheName{bla bla}`, and i want this to be the same when writing to the console via `pr` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I see from the other answer that you're probably referring to clojure.core/print-method (I didn't know that existed before now).

You may want to check out this old post:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/7yg07Fk3uuw

and don't forget to read up on hierarchies in case that comes into play:

- https://clojure.org/reference/multimethods

---

#### Update

Suppose you wanted to print a keyword.  The original `print-method` in `clojure.core_print.clj` is:

```
(defmethod print-method clojure.lang.Keyword [o, ^Writer w]
  (.write w (str o)))
```

perhaps just copy & rename the source, replacing the original `defmethod` with your own (*sans* the Writer):

```
(defn print-method-kw [o]
  (str o))

(defmethod print-method clojure.lang.Keyword [o, w]
  (.write w (str "<kw " (print-method-kw o) " />")))

(println "look:")
(println :hello)
```

results:

```
look:
<kw :hello />
```

---

#### Old Answer for Generic Functions:

Just capture the function before defining the multimethod:

```
(def original-print-method-placeholder print-method)

(defmulti print-method ...)
(defmethod print-method ...)
(defmethod print-method ...)
(defmethod print-method ...)
```

Yes, that works:

```
(defn greeting [x] (str "Nice day, " x ))

(greeting "you") => "Nice day, you"
```

but later in the file we redefine it:

```
(def orig-greeting greeting)  ; capture a reference to the function

(defmulti  greeting (fn [lang & args] lang))
(defmethod greeting :english [lang person]
  (str "(English accent) " (orig-greeting person)))
(defmethod greeting :french [lang person]
  (str "(French accent) " (orig-greeting person)))

(greeting :english "you")  => "(English accent) Nice day, you"
(greeting :french "you")   => "(French accent) Nice day, you"
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you may be able to use `(.getMethod print-method :default)` to get the default function so you can call it, though `clojure.core`'s `print-method` calls itself, so you'll end up with a stack overflow. It may work for other multimethods, depending on their implementation.

If you're wanting `print-method`'s default case, you might find that `print-simple` is close enough to what you want. (`print-method`'s default function calls `print-simple`.)